# morphism on manifolds - fundamentals

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Recently I decided to go back to the absolute basics and answer "why do we need differential geometry"? This is what I came up with:

One of the properties of smooth $n$-manifold $M$ is:

- $M$ is locally Euclidean of dimension n.

Now, let $(M,g)$ be $n$-dimensional Riemannan manifold. The previous property can be formulate in following way:

$\forall \ x\in U\subset M,\quad \exists \ \text{ a homeomorphism }\phi:U\rightarrow\tilde{U}\subset(\mathbb{R}^n,\delta) $,

such that
$\tilde{x}=\phi(x)$ is a local coordinate map (for $x\in M$ and $\tilde{x}\in \mathbb{R^n}$).

However, if we want to $\phi$ be a (local) **diffeomorphism**, the curvature tensor must vanish.

Is that it? That is basically why we need a "new" differential operators (e.g. covariant derivative, etc.)? Because (by definition) we have "only" homeomorphism rather than diffeomorphism?

Comment: Diffeomorphism doesn't require a metric: any set of coordinates on $M$ provides a local diffeomorphism with Euclidean space. I think you're talking about manifolds being [local isometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannian_manifold#Isometries) to Euclidean space.

Comment: Isn't that a bit of tautology? I always thought about an isometry as a diffeomorphism that can transform tensor fields properly (via pushforwards and pullbacks). Can you provide an example of a diffeomorphism on RM that is not an isometry?

Comment: Any linear map with determinant not equal to $0$, $1$, or $-1$.

Comment: Vector bundles (be they the tangent bundle or more general tensor bundles) don't need a metric for definition, and their transformations are defined, via pushforwards and pullbacks, using the transformation of the vectors. You don't need a metric to talk about the dual space (linear maps $\omega$ acting via $\omega(V)$ and the like). The metric is just a distinguished nondegenerate $(0,2)$ tensor field that gives a smooth choice of map $TM \to T^*M$, which gives one a way of measuring lengths.

Comment: Sure, I agree that you can define a diffeomorphism without metric. But that is not my point. What I mean is: starting with the Riemannian manifold, the answer to the question "why there are curved spaces?" is "because not every homeomorphism is differentiable (isometry)". Am I correct?

Comment: Differentiability is one thing. Introducing a notion of distance and talking about geometry (distances, angles) is a totally next step. You seem to keep conflating these.